# как убрать пробел в бордере

Tags: html, css

Делаю бордер для текста, а тут появляется огромный такой пробел после текста:

[image: огромный такой пробел]

```css
.heroes_card {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div class="heroes_card">
    <li><a href="{{url_for('shadow_fiend')}}" class="heroes">Shadow Fiend</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="heroes">Morphling</a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию тег `<div>` блочный и занимает всю доступную ширину родителя. Если необходимо, чтобы ширина была по контенту, то сделайте его строчным, указав `display: inline-*`:

```css
.heroes_card {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div class="heroes_card">
    <li><a href="{{url_for('shadow_fiend')}}" class="heroes">Shadow Fiend</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="heroes">Morphling</a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Или ограничьте максимальную ширину:

```css
.heroes_card {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  
  max-width: min-content;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div class="heroes_card">
    <li><a href="{{url_for('shadow_fiend')}}" class="heroes">Shadow Fiend</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="heroes">Morphling</a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```